# Still receiving SSL error "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED" after setting NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS

Tags: node.js

Since I was getting SSL errors (CERT_HAS_EXPIRED) for domains like https://www.dampfer-board.de/ I was trying to add current CAs to my application with

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/var/www/xxx/cacert.pem
```

cacert.pem is the following file: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
The env variable seems to be set correctly (confirmed by `console.log(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS)`), but I still receive the same ssl error.

The code snippet looks like this:

```
request.post({url: apiUrl, ecdhCurve: 'auto', headers: {
    'User-Agent': config.userAgent
}});
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: What version of node are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `openssl s_client -connect dampfer-board.de:443 -showcerts | openssl pkcs8` in the terminal returns this output.

```
depth=1 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
depth=1 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
```

In the server certificate chain there is an expired certificate for `AddTrust External CA Root`.

I resolved this for openssl by removing the certificate from the [list of certificates](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html) trusted by openssl.

I reckon that a similar fix can be applied for Node.
There is baked in the [Node source this certificate as a trusted root](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f1ae7ea343020f608fdc1ca77d9cdfe2c093ac72/src/node_root_certs.h#L116). It's about time [trust list got updated](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.6.0/doc/guides/maintaining-root-certs.md) as the certificate expired since `May 30, 2020`.

`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable extends the trusted roots baked in the source whereas the `ca` option replaces it.

Modify your request to be

```js
request.post({
  url: apiUrl, 
  ecdhCurve: 'auto', 
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': config.userAgent
  },
  agentOptions: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./var/www/xxx/cacert.pem')
  }
});
```

Comment: Even though I didn't use your fix, thanks to your answer I realized I was running Node v8 (very old version) which is not supported anymore and didn't get updated certificates. After updating to v10, everything seems to work now.